# Removing class-wide object instantiations from constructor in class file

Tags: java

I'm working on a project involving a memory analysis tool for Java. The tool works on class files and gives an upper bound for memory consumption for a given class. Currently, the tool isn't perfect, for example in the following code:

```
class Example {
    public Object o;

    public Example() {
        o = new Object();
    }
}
```

The space required by the Object o is counted double, because of the instantiation in the constructor. Currently, the user is required to manually remove the class-wide object instantiations from the constructor in order to get a more accurate upper bound of memory required.

Since we don't have the possibility to make changes to the analysis tool, we'd like to automate the process of stripping the object instantiations from constructors. However, since this would happen right before the tool does its magic, it happens on classfile-level.

How can we achieve this? I've been looking at [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/). However, I haven't found a way to achieve what I want. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Technically actual memory gets allocated at the `o = new Object();` line, you should count those instead of the declarations.

Comment: Except that `if (x==true) o = new Object1(); else o=new Object2();` would get counted twice.

Comment: Indeed in the case Tim B's example, the memory would be counted twice, which would be avoided by counting the declarations instead of the instantiations. Furthermore, we cannot influence the analysis tool itself, so we cannot make it count instantiations instead of declarations.